# How do I set Individual Input Volumes using a FFMPEG complex filter with Amix

Tags: ffmpeg

How do I set the individual volume levels for 4 individual inputs using FFMPEG and a complex filter?

This is the filter that I currently have.

`xstack=inputs=${inputs.length}:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0;amix=inputs=${inputs.length}`

Comment: Use `weights` option. http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately this worked for me.

```
ffmpeg -y -i https://input1.mp4 -i https://input2.mp4 -i https://input3.mp4 -i https://input4.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]volume=0.2[a0]; [1:a]volume=1.0[a1]; [2:a]volume=0.6[a2]; [3:a]volume=0.8[a3]; xstack=inputs=4:layout=0_0|w0_0|0_h0|w0_h0; [a0][a1][a2][a3]amix=inputs=4[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" output.mp4
```